# Excel Report generation

Tags: vb.net, excel

How can I set the column width and leave the top 10 rows empty in order to insert an image into my Excel report?

Here is my code:

```
If ComDset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    Try
        With Excel
            .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
            .Workbooks.Add()
            .Worksheets(1).Select()

            Dim i As Integer = 1
            For col = 0 To ComDset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                .cells(1, i).value = ComDset.Tables(0).Columns(col).ColumnName
                .cells(1, i).EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
                i += 1
            Next

            i = 2

            Dim k As Integer = 1
            For col = 0 To ComDset.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
                i = 2
                For row = 0 To ComDset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    .Cells(i, k).Value = ComDset.Tables(0).Rows(row).ItemArray(col)
                    i += 1
                Next
                k += 1
            Next

            filename = "ShiftReport" & Format(MdbDate, "dd-MM-yyyy") & ".xls"
            .ActiveCell.Worksheet.SaveAs(filename)
        End With

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Excel)
        Excel = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    ' The excel is created and opened for insert value. We most close this excel using this system
    Dim pro() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
    For Each i As Process In pro
        i.Kill()
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Range.ColumnWidth Property 
Returns or sets the width of all columns in the specified range. Read/write Variant.

Comment: Worksheet.Columns returns a range that contains the columns, then just set the Columnwidth property.

btw you don't need to leave the top 10 rows empty, just set the .RowHeight property of the rows (has to be between 0 and 409)